# Language selection for \maketitle

Tags: babel, languages, texworks

I am writing a document in English but when I use `\maketitle`, it inserts the date in Czech (my mother language I normally use when writing other text documents).

I have set my IDE (TexWorks) to English but it does not work.

I use `\usepackage[czech]{babel}` improt because my Name is spelled with Czech diacritics. When I remove this import, I get the following exception:

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option czech yet.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.4 \select@language{czech}
```

I do not use any other command that would require the Czech import in my document so I dont know where this exception come from...

These are all imports I use:

```
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
```

Could you suggest whats wrong? Thank you for any tips!

Comment: This happens any time you remove a language after having run LaTeX on the document: the language choice is saved in the `.aux` file. Just ignore the error and go on; in the next run the error will not be raised. Alternatively, remove the `.aux` file for the first run after the change in loaded languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this works, although I have no idea how czech diacritics are generated...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[english,czech]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}


\title{A very sophisticated document}%
\author{By Smajl}%
\date{\selectlanguage{english}\today}%
\begin{document}


\maketitle


\selectlanguage{english}% for the rest

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, it doesn't work. The language for the document will be Czech, giving wrong hyphenation. You should add `\selectlanguage{english}`, which would be equivalent to not loading Czech at all.

Comment: @egreg: Agreed, I had `\selectlanguage{english}` in a previous version, but deleted it afterwards.

Answer (score 7):

There is no need to add support for the Czech language just to type a name. Diacritics will be understood and correctly set so long as you add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

I found [somebody who seems also interested in TeX](http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=6c-EzFcAAAAJ&hl=it) and will use his name for the example (it has many diacritics, as you see, and one typical of the Czech language).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[english]{babel} % not necessary

\begin{document}

\author{Michal Růžička}
\title{Some title}

\maketitle

This is the text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I agree also with your solution, but what, if there are some parts of the file which require nevertheless native language settings? Although rare, it might happen.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer `\usepackage[czech,english]{babel}` and `\begin{otherlanguage*}{czech}<text in Czech>\end{otherlanguage*}`, or another featured command of `babel`.