# Beamer - maketitle two language

Tags: beamer, babel, greek

I am trying to have a title page with the title be in English and the rest elements in Greek. I search and tried a lot but I can' get it work.

I tried `\title{English title}`, `\title{{\lat English title}}`, `\title{{\selectlanguage{english} English title}}`.

I removed babel but some characters are [not being recognized](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/203804/95204).

I am using SublimeText 3 with LatexTools as builder and engine pdflatex.

I tried: [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173733/language-selection-for-maketitle) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/351438/titles-in-two-languages).

The error log is huge. I posted the the first few lines.

> Argument of \bbl@pop@lang has an extra }. [\begin{document}]
>
> Paragraph ended before \bbl@pop@lang was complete.
>
> Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@@ProtectSpacesFi was complete.
>
> LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [\begin{document}]
>
> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. [\begin{document}]
>
> Use of \HyPsd@RemoveMask doesn't match its definition. [\begin{document}]
>
> Undefined control sequence. [\begin{document}]
>
> Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@RemoveBraces was complete.
>
> LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}. [\begin{document}]
>
> Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. [\begin{document}]
>
> Argument of \HyPsd@CheckCatcodes has an extra }. [\begin{document}]
>
> Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@CheckCatcodes was complete. [\begin{document}]
>
> Paragraph ended before \HyPsd@RemoveMask was complete. [\begin{document}]

```
%\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\documentclass[hide notes greek]{beamer}
%\documentclass[notes=only]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Rochester}
}

%Packages

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,matrix}

%Math Fonts

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\bibliography{references}

\newcommand{\lat}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gre}{\selectlanguage{greek}}

\hypersetup{
    unicode=true
}

%Page Title Variables

\title{English title}
\subtitle{A greek subtitle}
\institute{A greek name institute}
\author{Greek name}
\subject{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: LuaLaTeX with [tag:fontspec], solving the problem once and for all.

Comment: Thanks! I will take look. Didn't know the existence of LualaTex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try with `\foreignlanguage{english}{English title}`

```
%\documentclass[notes]{beamer}
\documentclass[hide notes greek]{beamer}
%\documentclass[notes=only]{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
    \usetheme{Rochester}
}

%Packages

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tree-dvips}
\usepackage{lmodern}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lm

\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing,backgrounds,positioning,fit,matrix}

%Math Fonts

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}{\insertbiblabel}

\bibliography{references}

\newcommand{\lat}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gre}{\selectlanguage{greek}}

\hypersetup{
    unicode=true
}

%Page Title Variables

\title{\foreignlanguage{english}{English title}}
\subtitle{A greek subtitle}
\institute{A greek name institute}
\author{Greek name}
\subject{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Off topic: No need for `\usepackage{color}` and `\usepackage{graphicx}`, beamer already provides these functionalities.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It solved my problem. Thanks also about the off topics. Didn't know it.